# Independence of stochastic processes

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions

Suppose that $(X_t)$ and $(Y_t)$ are stochastic processes defined on the same probability space whose sample paths belong to some Hilbert space $K$ (or more generally some function space). We may view these processes as $K$-valued random variables, hence we may talk about their independence as random variables.

> Is the [independence of stochastic processes](http://planetmath.org/IndependentStochasticProcesses) $(X_t)$ and $(Y_t)$ equivalent to the independence of the corresponding $K$-valued random variables?

Comment: I think the answer to your question is **yes**; see  Lemma 2 in \S 2.2 of http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/385/BrownianMotion.pdf

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee thank you. However I fail to see the connection with my question?

Comment: I do not think this is a research level question, so I vote to migrate this question to MSE.

Answer (score 4):

The real question is: are $X = (X_t)$ and $Y = (Y_t)$ indeed $K$-valued random variables? This is not so obvious in continuous time, and in fact the answer may depend on the choice of the $\sigma$-field in $K$.

If $K$ is equipped with the product $\sigma$-field (generated by cylinder sets), then the answer is clearly "yes": $X = (X_t)$ and $Y = (Y_t)$ are $K$-valued random variables, and they are independent.

On the other hand, if $K$ is equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-field associated with the norm in $K$, then the answer can be "no". For example, take $\Omega = [0, 1]$ with the Lebesgue $\sigma$-field, consider a non-measurable set $E \subset \Omega$, and define the process $X_t$ so that $X_t(\omega) = 1$ if $t = \omega$ and $\omega \in E$, $X_t(\omega) = 0$ otherwise. Then $X_t$ has bounded, Borel-measurable paths, but $$\{\omega \in \Omega : \|X(\omega)\| < 1\} = E$$ is not measurable (here $\|X(\omega)\| = \sup \{|X_t(\omega)| : t \in [0, 1]\}$).

What happens if we know *a priori* that $X$ and $Y$ are measurable with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-field? I guess it is still possible to cook up an example in which $X$ and $Y$ may fail to be independent as $K$-valued variables, but I do not know that.

If, however, your processes are regular enough (right-continuous with left limits should do), then independence over the cylinder $\sigma$-field should imply independence over the Borel $\sigma$-field.

Comment: I don't understand this answer, and it seems the counterexample you give violates one of the basic assumptions of a stochastic process, namely measurability with respect to the underlying $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: The problem with $L_2[0,1]$ is that the evaluation functionals are not well-defined as the space comprises equivalence classes of functions. However the processes of interest are indeed cadlag. Not sure how to reconcile these two things.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee: Each $X_t$ is measurable: if $t \notin E$, then $X_t$ is constant $0$, otherwise it is $1$ at a single $\omega$ and $0$ otherwise. Of course this is a pathological example, but it is a stochastic process according to the most usual definition (a collection of random variables).

Comment: @user512365: If your processes are cadlag, you are likely good to go. However, I do not understand the comment about evaluation functionals: if $X_t(\omega)$ is not defined "pointwise", but almost all $t$ only, then what do you really mean by saying that $(X_t)$ is a stochastic process? And how do you define independence of stochastic proceses?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki I do not see why the *corresponding K-valued random variables* (that the OP asked about) should be equipped with anything other than the $\sigma$-field generated by the cylinder sets.   Of course the definition of a stochastic process varies, but this is the definition of a stochastic process I am familiar with.